FindInstance and Integers option
I am looking for integer solutions of
$$a^3 + b + 1 = (b^2 - c^2)^2$$
Some solutions are
$$(a, b, c) = (6,8,7); (46,7,19);(665, 8575, 8584)$$
I tried this with the FindInstance command as
  FindInstance[{a^3 + b + 1 == (b^2 - c^2)^2}, {a, b, c}, Integers, 10]

I was under the impression that this would try to find 10 integer solutions, but I may be interpreting Integers incorrectly, as it returns
$$\left\{\{a\to 238,b\to -13481273,c\to 13481273\},\{a\to 329,b\to -35611290,c\to 35611290\},\left\{a\to 927,b\to -796597907,c\to -\sqrt{\sqrt{77}+634568225436780649}\right\},\{a\to 655,b\to -281011376,c\to -281011376\},\left\{a\to 880,b\to -681471954,c\to -\sqrt{\sqrt{47}+464404024088578116}\right\},\{a\to -260,b\to 17575999,c\to 17575999\},\left\{a\to 689,b\to -327082731,c\to -\sqrt{\sqrt{39}+106983112918418361}\right\},\{a\to -915,b\to 766060874,c\to -766060874\},\left\{a\to -958,b\to 879217998,c\to -\sqrt{\sqrt{87}+773024288007128004}\right\},\left\{a\to 907,b\to -746142552,c\to -\sqrt{2 \left(278364353952536352-\sqrt{23}\right)}\right\}\right\}$$
The default FindInstance returns $(0, 0, 1)$.
Is there a better way to solve this, is there a way to get the positive integer solutions shown  above and does the output above make sense based on the integer option?

FindInstance[{a^3+b+1==(b^2-c^2)^2,-10^6<a<10^6,-10^6<b<10^6,-10^6<c<10^6},{a,b,c},Integers,10] If you restrict a,b,c to be all positive then it complains that it can't find solutions and can't prove to itself that they don't exist.

@Bill: Thanks! Do you think the radical roots it is returning is a bug?

I don't know and probably can't know. Perhaps there are a few words buried deep in the documentation that hint why it might be returning radicals. I suppose if you want to wait long enough you might try iterating through positive integer a,b and see if you can find a positive integer c using Solve or Reduce. Do not know. Have not seen this behavior before.

Version 13.0.1 returns only integers solutions as it should so I guess it is a new bug introduced in later versions.

An exact duplicate asked yesterday:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5001818/solution-for-find-all-positive-integers-a-b-c-that-satisfies-a3b1-b2-c2

I use Math Stack Exchange as a source of proles to see if MA can solve them.

@Moo  That's good but you really need to give that source because of the work that's already been done.  Otherwise, you can be wasting time of the experts here.

The results vary greatly depending on the order of the variables: Grid[Table[{vars, FindInstance[a^3 + b + 1 == (b^2 - c^2)^2, vars, Integers,      10]}, {vars, Permutations[{a, b, c}]}], Dividers -> All]

@A.Kato: very interesting.


A bug also in version 14.1.
We can Reduce before FindInstance.

eqn = a^3 + b + 1 == (b^2 - c^2)^2;
sol = FindInstance[{Reduce[eqn, {a, b, c}]}, {a, b, c}, Integers, 10]
And @@ (eqn /. sol)


{{a -> -820, b -> 551367999, c -> -551367999}, {a -> -586,  b -> 201230055, c -> -201230055}, {a -> -488, b -> 116214271,  c -> -116214271}, {a -> -256, b -> 16777215,  c -> -16777215}, {a -> -2, b -> 7, c -> -7}, {a -> -1, b -> 0,  c -> 0}, {a -> 61, b -> -226982, c -> -226982}, {a -> 110,  b -> -1331001, c -> -1331001}, {a -> 560, b -> -175616001,  c -> -175616001}, {a -> 985, b -> -955671626, c -> -955671626}}


True


Or add  b>c or b<c.

eqn = a^3 + b + 1 == (b^2 - c^2)^2;
sol = FindInstance[{eqn, b < c}, {a, b, c}, Integers, 10]
And @@ (eqn /. sol)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Rather than specifying the domain Integers, specify that the variables are elements of the domain. Also, specify that c is positive.
sys = a^3 + b + 1 == (b^2 - c^2)^2 && {a, b, c} \[Element] Integers &&
    c > 0;

sol = FindInstance[sys, {a, b, c}, 10]

(* {{a -> -915, b -> 766060874, c -> 766060874}, {a -> -188, 
  b -> 6644671, c -> 6644671}, {a -> 972, b -> -918330049, 
  c -> 918330049}, {a -> -362, b -> 47437927, 
  c -> 47437927}, {a -> -472, b -> 105154047, 
  c -> 105154047}, {a -> 692, b -> -331373889, 
  c -> 331373889}, {a -> -341, b -> 39651820, 
  c -> 39651820}, {a -> 908, b -> -748613313, 
  c -> 748613313}, {a -> -2, b -> 7, c -> 7}, {a -> -474, 
  b -> 106496423, c -> 106496423}} *)

And @@ (sys /. sol)

(* True *)


There seems to be a bug in version 14. If we look at the non-integer c-s we see that they are close to be integers. (error less than 10^-7). But still they are not integers.
cs = {-Sqrt[634568225436780649 + Sqrt[77]], -Sqrt[
    464404024088578116 + Sqrt[47]], -Sqrt[
    106983112918418361 + Sqrt[39]], -Sqrt[
    773024288007128004 + Sqrt[87]], -Sqrt[
    2 (278364353952536352 - Sqrt[23])]};
N[cs, 16]
N[cs, 17]
Round[cs, 10^-7]


{-7.965979070000000*10^8, -6.814719540000000*10^8,
-3.270827310000000*10^8, -8.792179980000000*10^8,
-7.461425520000000*10^8}

{-7.9659790700000001*10^8, -6.8147195400000001*10^8,
-3.2708273100000001*10^8, -8.7921799800000001*10^8,
-7.4614255199999999*10^8}

{-796597907, -681471954, -327082731, -879217998, -746142552}

